# Fetch objects in Core Data through one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have this `One-to-Many` `relationship` in `Core Data`:

[image]

Each `SBQChrono` can have many `SBQLaps`.

In my model I have the class `SBQLap`:

```
@interface CILap : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * lapDate;

@end
```

And the class `SBQChrono`:

```
@interface CIChrono : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * startDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * stopDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOrderedSet *laps;

@end
```

I get all the `SBQChrono` `entities` doing:

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:kChronoEntityName];

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [appContext.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

How can I get the specified `SBQLap` entitys per each `SBQChrono` I find? Ive read a lot of posts and cant get the solution.

**UPDATE**:

After trying to cast the `NSManagedObject`, I realized that the laps is returned as nil value.

Doing:

for (NSManagedObject *oneObject in objects) {

```
    CIChrono *chrono=(CIChrono *)oneObject;

    NSLog(@"startDate %@", chrono.startDate);
    NSLog(@"stopDate %@", chrono.stopDate);
    NSLog(@"laps %@",chrono.laps);
```

}
I get the message:

```
2014-01-28 14:39:48.379 Chrono[2341:70b] startDate 2014-01-28 12:27:53 +0000
2014-01-28 14:39:48.380 Chrono[2341:70b] stopDate 2014-01-28 12:27:54 +0000
2014-01-28 14:39:48.380 Chrono[2341:70b] -[NSManagedObject laps]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b959b0
2014-01-28 14:39:48.383 Chrono[2341:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject laps]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b959b0'
```

Thanks

Comment: A single array containing all laps for all chrono's in the `objects` array?

Comment: Basically by accessing the NSOrderedSet. CoreData will transparently fetch them, as you access them. If you generate the NSManagedObject subclasses from the Model Editor, Xcode will generate the accessors for you.

Comment: I want to find only the laps of a specified Chrono ;) Thanks

Comment: At what stage have you created all these objects in the first place? Have you created any lap objects and assigned them to the Chrono relationship?

Comment: I created 2 entitys related to the 2 objects in Core Data Model Editor, and assigned as well the relationships between theese entitys from Core Data Editor. I only use the NSObject classes when I get all the data from Core Data the first time the app runs, for creating data model to show all the information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of interesting answers on this one.

The answer is very simple and does not require subclassing `NSManagedObject` to access the objects in a relationship.  You just need to use KVC (Key Value Coding) to access those objects.  This is true of relationships and attributes.

If you want to use synthesized methods you can by subclassing as some have hinted at but that is not necessary.

Here is an extension to your example that you posted in your question:

```
for (NSManagedObject *oneObject in objects) {

    CIChrono *chrono=(CIChrono *)oneObject;

    NSLog(@"startDate %@", [chrono valueForKey:@"startDate");
    NSLog(@"stopDate %@", [chrono valueForKey:@"stopDate"]);
    NSLog(@"laps %@", [chrono valueForKey:@"laps"]);

    NSSet *laps = [chrono valueForKey:@"laps"];

    for (NSManagedObject *lap in laps) {
        NSLog(@"Lap entity: %@", lap);
    }
}
```

Note the `-valueForKey:` calls.  Those are Key Value Coding which `NSManagedObject` instances (and all other Objective-C objects) respond to.  I would suggest reading the documentation on KVC and KVO.

Comment: Ill check the KVC and KVO documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each `SQBChrono` object contains a set of `SBQLap` objects that are associated with it.  Look at your `SQBChrono` properties

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOrderedSet *laps;
```

`laps` is a property that contains the many `SBQLap` objects to one `SQBChrono` object.

You can get an array from the set like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:kChronoEntityName];
NSError *error;
NSArray *chronoObjectArray = [appContext.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

for (SQBChrono * chrono in chronoObjectArray) {
    NSArray *lapsArray = [chrono.laps array];
    NSLog("Chrono: %@   laps: %@", chrono.startDate, lapsArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've added the SBQChrono objects to an array you will need to cast it:

```
SQBChrono *anObject = (SQBChrono *)objects[0];
```

Then you can:

```
anObject.laps;
```

Will give you the NSSet of all associated objects ?

Answer (score 0):

Your array objects contains all your SBQChrono objects.

You can get all the SBQLaps associated with one chrono by doing:

`SQBChrono * myChrono = objects[indexOfTheDesiredChrono];`

The laps of the chrono are then in myChrono.laps, which is a NSOrderedSet (collection) of SBQLaps. Can be turn into an array like this :

`NSArray * myChronoLaps = [myChrono.laps array]`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch objects which have a relationship to 'SBQChrono'.

This can be done with two fetch requests, first fetch all the 'SBQChrono' objects & then perform a second request for 'SBQLap' entities with a predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chrono IN %@",objects]
```

Comment: Unnecessary since he already has the `SBQChrono` object fetched. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the model screenshot and code that you posted, it appears that the model has the relationship name set as `lap` (singular) but your class definition is using `laps` (plural). Core Data would be implementing an accessor for `lap`, but doesn't understand `laps` since it doesn't match the name in the model. Changing the model to say `laps` should fix that problem.